# Calling get with incomplete key in Google data store?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

What happens when you have an *incomplete* key (like `new Key("books")`) and using it for `get` on datastore?

Signature of `get`

```
Entity get(Key key) throws EntityNotFoundException;
```

tells me that an `Entity` is returned, and therefore, I can not expect to have all the books. What GAE will do in this case? Will it throw an exception or it will return an `Entity` that has `NestedEntities` for each book in the collection?

EDIT

I am talking about using this from Java (but the concept should be the same for other implementations). Anyway, the **incomplete key** is one that contains only the name, but not the id. If you go to the [javadoc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity) of the `Entity` and search for the term "incomplete" you will get the idea what is it about.

Comment: I don't think I am understanding you properly. What do you mean by incomplete key?

Also, could you show us how you fetch the Entity, the actual code would be good. It looks like you are using Java in this case, right?

Comment: Hey @LiY Ive update the question. You can find more about incomplete keys in the datastore documentation. The code here is just calling that method `get` with an incomplete key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A get always looks up an exact key and returns the entity with that key. You can't do a get with an incomplete key. You would need to do a query on the entity type.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you mean. You create the `Entity` but you didn't do perform a `put()` on it. In these case, the Entity is not actually saved in the datastore until you do a `datastore.put(Entity)`.

All the editing and changes you make to an `Entity` needs a `put()` to complete the transaction, without the `put()`, it's not saved in the datastore, which you can verify in your console.developers.google.com datastore view.

So to answer your question, the `Entity` is not found in the datastore because datastore didn't save it.

You need a bit more, so you created a `Key` called `Books`, but is your `Entity` connected to that `Key`? You need something like this:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

Key booksKey = new Key("Books", "Books");

Entity booksCollection = new Entity (booksKey);
```

Afterwards, you do your editing.

```
ArrayList<String> books = new ArrayList<String>(); // This just creates an empty ArrayList for whatever books you want to put in there. In this example, I just left it blank.

booksCollection.setProperty("books", books);
```

Then you finalize and save it in the datastore:

```
datastore.put(booksCollection);
```

Once this is done, you will see the Entity book in your datastore (in console.developers.google.com).

To call the `Entity` you will need to get the `Key`, then do a `datastore.get()`.

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

Key booksKey = new Key("Books", "Books");

Entity booksCollection = null;

booksCollection = datastore.get(booksKey);
```

Comment: Almost there:) I created just a `Key('books')` and want to do `get(key)` to fetch all the books. There are already books stored in the datastore. Would this work?